# ManyRelatedManager return None

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

I have two models:

```
Rubric(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()

Magazine(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField()
    rubrics = models.ManyToManyField(
              Rubric, related_name="magazines", )
```

When I try to access all rubric names for my magazines, I have `None` names

```
>>> names = [i.rubrics.name for i in Magazine.objects.all()]
>>> [None, None..]
```

What I do wrong, help me understand this, please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution. When I call MtM field `rubrics`, I call `manager` for `Rubric` model, so I need to use the manager's method.
`[i.rubrics.all() for i in News.objects.all()]`